# How can I make a programmatic click in react-leaflet?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am working on a map webapp, that should react on navigation from another route in the following ways:

- fly to coordinates
- click on them programatically

```
    // fly
        const map = useMap();
    const newCenterRef = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
      if (signatura && markerData && markerData.geojson) {

        if (lat !== undefined && lng !== undefined) {
          map.flyTo([lng, lat], 18);

        } else {
          console.error("Invalid coordinates:", lat, lng);
        }
      }
    }, [signatura, markerData, lat, lng]);
```

i managed to make it fly, but am struggling with the second request.

so far I have tried the 'leaflet marker' way

```
 newCenterRef.current.fire('click')
```

but my markers are derived from a customized BetterWMS TileLayer, so that didn't work.

Then I tried the 'leaflet object' way

```
map.fireEvent('click', { latlng: L.LatLng(lat, lng) });
```

no luck either, don't know why.
Any ideas?

the example is [here](https://github.com/ydrea/rleaf/tree/flytomap).

Comment: Have you tried adapting https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/issues/649#issuecomment-277686891 ? You'll want to map the 'click' events there as well.